# jQuery submit() Not Executing When Form Submitted

Tags: jquery, html, forms, validation, submit-button

I am trying to run a PHP file when a user submits the form.  However, the submit() function never runs.  I have read many posts making suggestions about this and none of them have resolved the problem.  So I have a form that looks like this:

```
<body>
<form id="signupform">
    <div id="required">
        <table>
            Form fields
        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="notrequired">
        <table>
            More form fields
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="Submit" name="action">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#signupform").submit(function(e) {
            alert("Please work!");

            $.ajax({
                type    : 'POST',
                url     : 'process.php',
                data    : JSON.stringify($'signupform').serializeArray(),
                dataType: 'json'
            })

            //More code
        });
    }););
</script>
</body>
```

Nothing, except type, has the value 'Submit' in the file.  I have tried it with and without the $(document).ready().  So I'm pretty much out of ideas.  Any suggestions.

Oh, it doesn't work on any browsers.

Comment: Any errors in the browser console? You'd want to add `e.preventDefault()` to your function to stop the default form submit, but if even the alert isn't showing there's obviously some other problem.

Comment: You missed a semicolon when closing ajax request. Fix it maybe? Also, any error in browser console? EDIT: and you've missed a `}` when closing document.ready function, too.

Comment: @BasitSaeed Javascript allows you to omit semicolons at the end of the line.

Comment: Does the alert happen?  If not, are you including jQuery anywhere?

Comment: @Barmar perhaps it is the syntax error as the document.ready function is not being closed properly.

Comment: You have an extra `);` at the end of the code. If that's in the real code, it will cause a syntax error.

Comment: Sorry for the late replies.  The semicolon comes later in the code after a `.fail(data)` function.  I do call `e.preventDefault()` at the end of the code.  And no the alert does not happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a syntax error on this line:

```
data    : JSON.stringify($'signupform').serializeArray(),
```

You missed the parentheses in the call to `$()`.

Also you missed the `#` to select by id, and you *might* want [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) rather than `.serializeArray()`, though obviously that isn't actually a syntax error.

It should be:

```
data    : JSON.stringify($('#signupform').serialize()),
// add parens here -------^ ^   and here ------------^
// add # here --------------/
```

Also there was an extra `);` at the end of your function that should be removed.

You don't really need the `JSON.stringify()` either:

```
 data    : $('#signupform').serialize(),
```

And somewhere (perhaps you already have this in your "more code" section) you want to stop the default form submit action:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Ok, I added the parentheses, thank you.  Will using `serialize()` let PHP read the data passed though `$_POST[]`?  I thought I had to use `serializeArray()` for that.

Comment: Try it either way and see for yourself.

Comment: I tried using serialize() and it worked perfectly, however, when I leave out JSON.stringify() nothing happens when I click the submit button.  Is there anything else you see wrong with my AJAX request?  No matter what, the data doesn't seem to be sent properly, but when a change the form action to "process.php" it works fine.

Comment: If you're saying it works perfectly with both `.serialize()` and `JSON.stringify()` then stick with that. If you change and nothing happens there's probably some syntax error stopping the whole thing running. Do you get any errors in the browser's console?

Comment: I think it may be an unrelated problem to this question, but mainly what is happening is even when the ajax request is a success and the form is added to the database, the function runs the '.fail()' function.

Comment: I would think that is related to what your `process.php` returns. You've specified `dataType: 'json'` - that is the expected format of the _response_ from the server, not the format of the request.

Answer (score 0):

Add this edited code in your **script** tag :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#signupform").submit(function(e) 
    {
        alert("Please work!");

        $.ajax({
            type    : 'POST',
            url     : 'process.php',
            data    : JSON.stringify($('#signupform').serializeArray()),
            dataType: 'json'
        })

        //More code
    });
});
```

Hope this helps.